# Given a list remove index 0,4,5 from the list if there exist

Tags: python

Down below is my answer. I am wondering if there is a way to delete index 0,4,5 at the same time to make it looks wiser. Thanks

```
def remove_item_045(a_list):
    if len(a_list) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(a_list) >= 1 and len(a_list) < 4:
        del(a_list[0])
    elif len(a_list) <= 5:
        del(a_list[0])
        del(a_list[3])
    else:
        del(a_list[0])
        del(a_list[3])
        del(a_list[3])
    return a_list
```

Comment: The best solution ever!

Answer (score 4):

A Pythonic way to solve your problem is not to remove what you do not want but to keep what you want:

```
a_list = list(range(10))
a_list
#[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a_list = [item for i,item in enumerate(a_list) if i not in {0,4,5}]
a_list
#[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: In terms of a big list this would be a bit less efficient than simply removing the desired elements, though you're right about pythonicness.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy: In practice, maybe. In theory, this is faster though; it's a single `O(n)` operation, not a `O(n*m)` operation (where `m` is the number of indices to remove). The only reason explicit one-by-one removal would win is that it avoids a Python-level loop over the whole `list`, in favor of three implicit copy down loops over the `list`.

Answer (score 1):

First: don't use `del(list[index])`, use `list.pop(index)`.

Second: Instead of using a bunch of `if` statements to make sure you don't have an error, just put everything inside a `try:` block and ignore the exception you get. The code will throw an error as soon as you try to remove an index the list doesn't have, and you can just use that as your cue to exit:

```
def remove_item_045(a_list):
    try:
        a_list.pop(0)   # remove index 0
        a_list.pop(3)   # remove index 4
        a_list.pop(3)   # remove index 5
    except e:
        pass
    return a_list
```

Comment: Both your code and the OP's code suffer from the problem of "magic numbers": it is not clear how 0, 4, and 5 become 0, 3, and 3. Also, `del` is actually better than `pop` because it does not return the deleted value (which you don't use, anyway). Finally, performance-wise, `if` is more efficient than `try-except`.

Comment: You could avoid the 'magic numbers' problem by simply inverting the logic: start by removing index 5, then 4, then 0. And yes, use `del` if you aren't going to use the returned value from `pop`

Comment: @DYZ: `if` is more efficient if you expect the failure case to be as common as the success case, and you only need to test once to match the exception catching behavior (and even then, in CPython, it's not that much more efficient; CPython is slow enough in general that exception handling slowness isn't nearly as bad as in lower level languages like C++). I tend to favor EAFP over LBYL patterns in general in Python (they're generally more thread-safe). In this case, a single `try` block that rarely executes the `except` block is likely faster than testing for valid indices over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing for it.

```
def remove_item_045(a_list):
    return a_list[1:4] + a_list[6:]
```

Also, there is a bug in your code. `< 4` should be `<= 4` in line 4.

The advantage of this method is that as long as it is a sequence that supports slicing and addition it would work.

```
>>> remove_item_045('0123456')
'1236'
>>> remove_item_045(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
['b', 'c', 'd', 'g']
>>> remove_item_045(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'))
('b', 'c', 'd', 'g')
>>> remove_item_045(b'0123456')
b'12367'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator `itemgetter()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

l = list(range(10))

ig = itemgetter(slice(1, 4), slice(6, None))
list(chain.from_iterable(ig(l)))
# [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```